# Handlebars: combine values from JSON to create a new input for the template

Tags: javascript, html, json, templates

I have created a Handlebars template that displays the data directly from JSON. However, I also need to display the data is not directly in the JSON, but has to be concatenated from different values in it.

As an example, if I have the JSON:

```
{
 "1": {"name": "Bob", "surname": "Bradley", "domain": "gmail"},
 "2": {"name": "Rob", "surname": "Smedley", "domain": "yahoo"}
}
```

I want the Handlebars template to contain the name, the surname, and the email **constructed from the values**, like such:

*Handlebars template*

```
<script id="user_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <li>
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <p>{{surname}}</p>
        <p>{{email}}</p> // I want "name.surname@domain.com" here
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

The way I used this in Javascript (without the email part which is now the problem) was:

```
var raw_template = $('#user_template').html();

// Compile that into an handlebars template
var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);

// Retrieve the placeHolder where the Users will be displayed
var placeHolder = $("#users_table");

var html = template(users); // "users" is a JSON object received from AJAX controller

// Render the posts into the page
placeHolder.append(html);
```

Now, what would be the (good) way to somehow combine the values from JSON into another value (the email) and have it in the Handlebars template?

Comment: you will need to use the email or store it somewhere, or is it just to show? if is just build and show with no other purpose , you can build an handlebars helper for the job!

Answer (score 0):

you could build this helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('buildEmail', 
    function(name, lastName, domain, options) {
        return name + lastName + '@' + domain + '.com';
    });
```

and then just call it , on your template.

```
{{#each this}}
<li>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <p>{{surname}}</p>
    <p>{{{buildEmail name surname domain}}}</p>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Well actually I need to use it, like click on it as the URL <a href>. I guess its still possible with the helper, just put in the <a href> tag, right?

Comment: yes you can just put the value inside the <a href> , the helper is just working like the normal {{name}} returning a string, the difference is that is being parsed by a specific function built by you, instead of base one that handlebars provide